# How we connect to mysql databases from other devices

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

How we connect to mysql databases from other devices linked to the network

Comment: Did you connect through  web app or throug other database system? Please, post more details

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a working connection on your local computer, then somewhere in your code you will have the text **localhost** or **127.0.0.1**. You simply need to change this code to the IP address of your computer hosting the database.

Do you have any more details, such as how you are trying to connect? Or your operating systems?

Comment: thank you all Has  3 devices and you put all IP Address devices
The first device 192.168.0.1 1
Second device 192.168.0.2 2
Third device 192.168.0.3 3
The first device in the database design software MySQL Workbench Program Access and ODBC databases you link
Now I want the second, third contact with the leaders of the data in the first device